# Hive-Spark error - java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have been trying to run a hive query at the Hive CLI, after configuring Hive to work Spark.

When `spark.master` is `local` it works just fine, but when I set it to my spark master `spark://spark-master:7077` I get the following error in the Spark logs:

```
15/11/03 16:37:10 INFO util.Utils: Copying /tmp/spark-5e39df85-d3d7-446f-86e9-d2699501f97e/executor-70d24a32-6913-479d-85b8-32e535dd3dbf/-11208827301446565026180_cache to /usr/local/spark/work/app-20151103163705-0000/0/./hive-exec-1.2.1.jar
15/11/03 16:37:11 INFO executor.Executor: Adding file:/usr/local/spark/work/app-20151103163705-0000/0/./hive-exec-1.2.1.jar to class loader
15/11/03 16:37:11 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectInputStream.java:2428)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1382)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1997)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1921)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I work with Spark 1.4.1 and Hive 1.2.1

Comment: Please check if this link is useful : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-8300

Comment: Thanks. I saw this. But I am not sure what to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for others that might be having the same issue, I managed to fix this and get past it, I think this was something with the HBase jars at the executors’ side (it was only occurring when running queries that were touching HBase through hive, and only in spark cluster mode).

My solution was to add to the spark-env.sh:

```
export SPARK_CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH
```

or

```
export SPARK_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/hbase-1.1.2/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase-1.1.2/lib/hbase-common-1.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase-1.1.2/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hbase-1.1.2/lib/hbase-server-1.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase-1.1.2/lib/hbase-client-1.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hive-1.2.1/lib/hive-hbase-handler-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hive-1.2.1/lib/hive-common-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hive-1.2.1/lib/hive-exec-1.2.1.jar
```

Alternatively, one can add to the hive-site.xml:

```
  <property>
    <name>spark.executor.extraClassPath</name>
    <value>/usr/local/hbase-1.1.2/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase-1.1.2/lib/hbase-common-1.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase-1.1.2/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/hbase-1.1.2/lib/hbase-server-1.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hbase-1.1.2/lib/hbase-client-1.1.2.jar:/usr/local/hive-1.2.1/lib/hive-hbase-handler-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hive-1.2.1/lib/hive-common-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hive-1.2.1/lib/hive-exec-1.2.1.jar</value>
  </property>
```